# How to fix "The name 'StandardPurchasingModule' does not exist in the current context" in Unity IAP 4.8.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I have followed this [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.purchasing@4.8/manual/DefiningProductsCoded.html)
var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
But I have encountered this error:
`Assets\Scripts\Scenes\CoinPurchaseScene\IAPManager.cs(79,53): error CS0103: The name 'StandardPurchasingModule' does not exist in the current context`

How can I fix this error?
Please Help Me!

Comment: Have you added the IAP package to your project? Is it the same version as the documentation you're following? Do you have the proper `using` statements at the top of your script?

Comment: I have added and I'm using Unity IAP 4.8.0.
Also imported `UnityEngine.Purchasing`.